# Linked lists equality exercise in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I have the following exercise I am quite close the solve it but not yet
can someone give some hints?

here it goes:

Suppose the linked list nodes are implemented using a class with the following structure:

```
from __future__ import annotations
class Node:
  data : int
  next : Node  #or None
```

Then an example is given

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, Data, Next):
    (self.data, self.next) = (Data, Next) 

node2 = Node(1, None)
node1 = Node(0, node2)
node0 = Node(0, node1)

Node1 = Node(1, None)
Node0 = Node(0, Node1)

assert is_equal(node0, Node0) == False
assert is_equal(node1, Node0) == True
```

The exercise also have this piece of code that you have complete

```
from __future__ import annotations

class Node:
     data : int
     next : Node  #or None

def is_equal(head1: Node, head2: Node)-> bool:
```

This is my solution but when I run through the auto correction it gives me the following error

self.assertFalse(is_equal(node0, Node0))

and I get a pass for this

assert is_equal(node1, Node0) == True

```
    while head1.data == head2.data:
      
        head1=head1.next
        head2=head2.next
        return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: You're only checking the first element.

Comment: ok but it says head1 and head2, what am I missing? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: You advance `head1`, but not `head2`. You aren't comparing corresponding nodes, only every node in the first list with the first node of the second list. (At least, you would be, if you weren't returning immediately before executing `head1 = head1.next`.

Comment: You need to compare two nodes, then *either* return `False` immediately or advance *both* pointers.

Comment: I have updated the code, and read your instructions but I still get the same error...

Comment: You are always returning `True` anytime two nodes are equal in the two lists. Obviously that is wrong, e.g. `[1, 2, 3 ] == [1, 5, 7]` is not true, but your code would say it is true

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in your attempt:

- The `while` loop will end in its first iteration because of the unconditional `return` in its body. So it doesn't actually *loop*
- The `while` loop has no protection against dereferencing `None` values, i.e. you should first make sure that `head1` is not `None` before inspecting `head1.data`
- Related to the previous point: there is no code that deals with the case where one list is longer than the other.

Here is a correction:

```
def is_equal(head1: Node, head2: Node)-> bool:
    # Make sure both are node references (not None) before accessing data
    while head1 and head2 and head1.data == head2.data:  
        head1 = head1.next
        head2 = head2.next
    return head1 is head2  # Both must be None for the result to be True
```

NB: The final condition may look strange, but when the loop ends normally, we know that at least one of the two variables is `None` or else that they are really different nodes (because they have different data), so by checking that they are the same thing, we actually check that they are *both* `None`.

Answer (score 0):

This the solution, the problem was comparing if the heads with different lenghts, therefore if they return none or not.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, Data, Next):
    (self.data, self.next) = (Data, Next)

 
def is_equal(head1: Node, head2: Node)-> bool:

    while head1 != None and head2 != None and head1.data == head2.data:
      
        head1=head1.next
        head2=head2.next
        
    if head1 != None or head2 !=None:
      return False
    else:
      return True
```